# JWT validation with external authority doesn't work. ASP .NET Core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, jwt

I am trying to authorize my requests using external service with IdentityServer4. I use following code

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = Configuration["IdentityUrl"];
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

        options.Audience = "myapi";
    });
```

I got my token using token client

```
var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(
       new PasswordTokenRequest
       {
           ClientId = clientId,
           ClientSecret = clientSecret,
           GrantType = GrantTypes.Password,
           Address = discoveryDocument.TokenEndpoint,
           UserName = user.UserName,
           Password = user.PasswordHash,
       });
```

It works and gives me token, but then when I try to authorize any request by including this token into authorization header it gives me 401 with no explanation. I don't see anything in output of either idenity server application or my client application.
This is what I do in postman to test authorization
[image]

Any ideas on what is wrong and how to debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to see what the logs says?

Or try to set this one to true in the AddJwtBearer options and then look at the response from the API to see if it contains some additional details about the failure.

```
options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
```

It it works you should see an additional WWW-authenticate header, like this one:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Sun, 02 Aug 2020 11:19:06 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"
```

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic:
[Troubleshooting JwtBearer authentication problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Thank you, it actually worked - invalid_scope was error in my case, which was casuse by some incorrect indentity server client settings in the database

Comment: Glad you found it!